# kali linux terminal crontab file

Tags: linux, terminal, cron

I do one `crontab` file

with this code

```
sum=0
i="y"

echo " Enter one no."
read n1
echo "Enter second no."
read n2
while [ $i = "y" ]
do
echo "1.Addition"
echo "2.Subtraction"
echo "3.Multiplication"
echo "4.Division"
echo "Enter your choice"
read ch
case $ch in
    1)sum=`expr $n1 + $n2`
     echo "Sum ="$sum;;
        2)sum=`expr $n1 - $n2`
     echo "Sub = "$sum;;
    3)sum=`expr $n1 \* $n2`
     echo "Mul = "$sum;;
    4)sum=`expr $n1 / $n2`
     echo "Div = "$sum;;
    *)echo "Invalid choice";;
esac
echo "Do u want to continue ?"
read i
if [ $i != "y" ]
then
    exit
fi
done
```

How can I make the program to do every 10 minutes   ... 
where can I put this command ?  `10 * * * *`

Then, I make another one vi file with the same code  can I make this file to crontab

Comment: this sounds like it belongs on [su]

Comment: What you want is impossible. Cronjobs don't have a terminal attached. Besides: the system can have multiple terminals, which one should the cronjob use?

Comment: `man crontab` and `man 5 crontab`. This: `10 * * * *` will run your job at 10 minutes after each hour, not every 10 minutes. Are you asking how to set up a crontab to run a job every 10 minutes, or are you asking how to make that particular script run as a cron job, or both?

Answer (score 0):

With Linux, you probably are using vixie-cron (see [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html)).  That provides an extension which simplifies *step* expressions.  For example

```
*/10 * * * * path-to-my-script
```

would run

Comment: It's not clear that this answers the question (because it's not clear what the question is).

Comment: The question was "How can I make the program to do every 10 minutes", and the answer included telling OP to read the manual page.